# AttributeError: object has no attribute in python in selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

While I am intermediate in python automation, I am trying to run a program, but unable to do it so, as I am seeing this
`AttributeError: object has no attribute`.
my Code is like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
import unittest



class goodsweb(unittest.TestCase):
    def setting(self):
        driverlocation ="/Users/new/Documents/Learning/Drivers/selenium-2.53.1/py/selenium/webdriver/chromedriver"
        os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = driverlocation
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(driverlocation)
        driver = self.driver
        url = "https://goods.theentertainerme.com/"
        driver.get(url)
        driver.maximize_window()
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)

    def test_data(self):

        driver =self.driver
        self.RegisterButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='logs']/li[2]//a[text()='Sign up']")
        self.FirstName = driver.find_element_by_id("registrationform-firstname")
        self.Lastname = driver.find_element_by_id("registrationform-lastname")
        self.EmailAddress = driver.find_element_by_id("registrationform-email")
        self.CountryofResidence = driver.find_element_by_id("registrationform-country_of_residence")
        self.DateofBirth = driver.find_element_by_id("registrationform-date_of_birth")
        self.Gender = driver.find_element_by_id("registrationform-gender")
        self.Password = driver.find_element_by_id("registrationform-password")
        self.ConfirmPassword = driver.find_element_by_id("registrationform-confirmpassword")


     def test_register(self):
        driver = self.driver
        self.RegisterButton.click()
        self.FirstName.send_keys("Taimoor")

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

and this is the error, which i am seeing.

```
line 38, in tearDown
    self.driver.close()
AttributeError: 'goodsweb' object has no attribute 'driver'
```

Please help me out here with explaination, that where I am making mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename def setting to def setUp.
setUp is a method of unittest.TestCase class that you want to override with your settings.